# Upload a file upon an asmx web service

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, upload, asmx

I have a problem while uploading a file via an asmx webservice.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<form method="post" action="/_wscommunity_/PublicCommunity.asmx/UploadTempPicture"      encoding="multipart/form-data" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_upload" target="upload_target">
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file_upload">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload">
<iframe name="upload_target" id="upload_target">&nbsp;</iframe>
</form>
```

On my Javascript File on the OnChange event :

```
$("form_upload").target = 'upload_target'; 
$("form_upload").submit();
```

When the form is submit I receive in my POST :

Parts        multipart/form-data

> file[] GIF89a 
>   �÷�������3��f����Ì��ÿ�+��+3�+f�+�+Ì�+ÿ�U��U3�Uf�U�UÌ�Uÿ���3�f��Ì�ÿ�ª��ª3�ªf�ª�ªÌ�ªÿ�Õ��Õ3�Õf�Õ�ÕÌ�Õÿ�ÿ��ÿ3�ÿf�ÿ�ÿÌ�ÿÿ3��3�33�f3�3�Ì3�ÿ3+�3+33+f3+3+Ì3+ÿ3U�3U33Uf3U3UÌ3Uÿ3�333f33Ì3ÿ3ª�3ª33ªf3ª3ªÌ3ªÿ3Õ�3Õ33Õf3Õ3ÕÌ3Õÿ3ÿ�3ÿ33ÿf3ÿ3ÿÌ3ÿÿf��f�3f�ff�f�Ìf�ÿf+�f+3f+ff+f+Ìf+ÿfU�fU3fUffUfUÌfUÿf�f3ffffÌfÿfª�fª3fªffªfªÌfªÿfÕ�fÕ3fÕffÕfÕÌfÕÿfÿ�fÿ3fÿffÿfÿÌfÿÿ���3�f��Ì�ÿ+�+3+f++Ì+ÿU�U3UfUUÌUÿ�3fÌÿª�ª3ªfªªÌªÿÕ�Õ3ÕfÕÕÌÕÿÿ�ÿ3ÿfÿÿÌÿÿÌ��Ì�3Ì�fÌ�Ì�ÌÌ�ÿÌ+�Ì+3Ì+fÌ+Ì+ÌÌ+ÿÌU�ÌU3ÌUfÌUÌUÌÌUÿÌ�Ì3ÌfÌÌÌÌÿÌª�Ìª3ÌªfÌªÌªÌÌªÿÌÕ�ÌÕ3ÌÕfÌÕÌÕÌÌÕÿÌÿ�Ìÿ3ÌÿfÌÿÌÿÌÌÿÿÿ��ÿ�3ÿ�fÿ�ÿ�Ìÿ�ÿÿ+�ÿ+3ÿ+fÿ+ÿ+Ìÿ+ÿÿU�ÿU3ÿUfÿUÿUÌÿUÿÿ�ÿ3ÿfÿÿÌÿÿÿª�ÿª3ÿªfÿªÿªÌÿªÿÿÕ�ÿÕ3ÿÕfÿÕÿÕÌÿÕÿÿÿ�ÿÿ3ÿÿfÿÿÿÿÌÿÿÿ������������!ù��ü�,���� ����÷ H° A�*\È0 �;

Source
-----------------------------292403007321689

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="Untitled.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif
```

> GIF89a
>   �÷�������3��f����Ì��ÿ�+��+3�+f�+�+Ì�+ÿ�U��U3�Uf�U�UÌ�Uÿ���3�f��Ì�ÿ�ª��ª3�ªf�ª�ªÌ�ªÿ�Õ��Õ3�Õf�Õ�ÕÌ�Õÿ�ÿ��ÿ3�ÿf�ÿ�ÿÌ�ÿÿ3��3�33�f3�3�Ì3�ÿ3+�3+33+f3+3+Ì3+ÿ3U�3U33Uf3U3UÌ3Uÿ3�333f33Ì3ÿ3ª�3ª33ªf3ª3ªÌ3ªÿ3Õ�3Õ33Õf3Õ3ÕÌ3Õÿ3ÿ�3ÿ33ÿf3ÿ3ÿÌ3ÿÿf��f�3f�ff�f�Ìf�ÿf+�f+3f+ff+f+Ìf+ÿfU�fU3fUffUfUÌfUÿf�f3ffffÌfÿfª�fª3fªffªfªÌfªÿfÕ�fÕ3fÕffÕfÕÌfÕÿfÿ�fÿ3fÿffÿfÿÌfÿÿ���3�f��Ì�ÿ+�+3+f++Ì+ÿU�U3UfUUÌUÿ�3fÌÿª�ª3ªfªªÌªÿÕ�Õ3ÕfÕÕÌÕÿÿ�ÿ3ÿfÿÿÌÿÿÌ��Ì�3Ì�fÌ�Ì�ÌÌ�ÿÌ+�Ì+3Ì+fÌ+Ì+ÌÌ+ÿÌU�ÌU3ÌUfÌUÌUÌÌUÿÌ�Ì3ÌfÌÌÌÌÿÌª�Ìª3ÌªfÌªÌªÌÌªÿÌÕ�ÌÕ3ÌÕfÌÕÌÕÌÌÕÿÌÿ�Ìÿ3ÌÿfÌÿÌÿÌÌÿÿÿ��ÿ�3ÿ�fÿ�ÿ�Ìÿ�ÿÿ+�ÿ+3ÿ+fÿ+ÿ+Ìÿ+ÿÿU�ÿU3ÿUfÿUÿUÌÿUÿÿ�ÿ3ÿfÿÿÌÿÿÿª�ÿª3ÿªfÿªÿªÌÿªÿÿÕ�ÿÕ3ÿÕfÿÕÿÕÌÿÕÿÿÿ�ÿÿ3ÿÿfÿÿÿÿÌÿÿÿ������������!ù��ü�,���� ����÷ H° A�*\È0 �; -----------------------------292403007321689--

And finally in my asmx webservice :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public AjaxResponse UploadTempPicture()
    {
        AjaxResponse response = new AjaxResponse();
        HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection;
        HttpPostedFile MyFile;
        MyFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        MyFile = MyFileCollection[0];
        ....
     }
```

The web service is call but I receive this error :

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Problem uploading file: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>       Parameter name: index

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Seems like MyFileCollection is empty.

Comment: Yes I try to debug it but yes MyFileCollection is empty and I don't know why! Maybe something missing in web.config!?